# How much is there overhead per single object memory allocation?

Tags: c++, c, memory, allocation

Say, if I call malloc(sizeof(int)), requesting 4 bytes, how much extra will be added by system (or std library?) to support memory management infrastructure? I believe there should be some. Otherwise, how the system would know how many bytes to dispose of when I call free(ptr).

UPDATE 1: It may sound like a 'too broad question' and, obviously, a C/C++ library specific, but what I am interested in, is a minimum extra memory needed to support a single allocation. Even not a system or implementation specific. For example, for binary tree, there is a must of 2 pointers - left and right children, and no way you can squeeze it.

UPDATE 2:
I decided to check it for myself on Windows 64.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int m = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    int n = (argc > 2) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        malloc(m);
    size_t peakKb(0);
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
            peakKb = pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize >> 10;
    printf("requested : %d kb, total: %d kb\n", (m*n) >> 10, peakKb);
    _getch();
}
```

requested : 0 kb, total: 2080 kb

1 byte:
requested : 976 kb, total: 17788 kb
extra: 17788 - 2080 - 976 = 14732 (+1410%)

2 bytes:
requested : 1953 kb, total: 17784 kb
extra: 17784 - 2080 - 1953 =  (+605% over)

4 bytes:
requested : 3906 kb, total: 17796 kb
extra: 17796 - 2080 - 3906 = 10810 (+177%)

8 bytes:
requested : 7812 kb, total: 17784 kb
extra: 17784 - 2080 - 7812 =  (0%)

UPDATE 3: THIS IS THE ANSWER TO MY QUESTION I’VE BEEN LOOKING FOR: In  addition to being slow, the genericity  of the default C++ allocator makes it  very  space inefficient for small  objects. The default  allocator manages a pool  of memory, and such management  often requires some extra memory. Usually, the bookkeeping memory  amounts to a few  extra bytes (4 to 32) for each block allocated with  new. If  you allocate 1024-byte blocks, the per-block space overhead is  insignificant (0.4% to  3%). If  you allocate 8-byte  objects, the per-object  overhead becomes 50% to  400%, a figure big enough to  make you worry  if  you allocate many  such small  objects.

Comment: I wouldn't know. Depends on the library.

Comment: @tobi303, there _must_ be addditional information maintained by the library about each allocation handed out for `free` of the object to work. It could be that housekeeping information is stored before the allocation handed out.

Comment: What you are asking is very implementation-defined. How any C library implements/maintains the malloc bookkeeping info very much depends on the implementation in question. Please be specific. Currently your Q is "too broad".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie hm ok I have to admit I had no idea what I was talking about. better delete that comment before someone takes it serious

Comment: One possible implementation is that every allocation is rounded up to a multiple of 16 bytes, and has 16 bytes of overhead for bookkeeping. Hence,  a 4 byte request would use 32 bytes of memory.

Comment: @Thebluefish, the pointer only knows an address in memory. The pointer does not know what the object is, nor how large it is. For `free` to work, there must be housekeeping information that the library maintains. C is a very low-level language.

Comment: Did you try searching [malloc+overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D%2Bmalloc%2Boverhead), there's loads of questions and answers out there, after reading through those, you should be able to work it out for yourself.

Comment: I've concluded that the theoretical minimum overhead is `2 * sizeof(void*)`. But that's so unlikely a scenario that it may never have happened in the real world.

Comment: @jwdonahue your theoretical minimum is not necessarily correct. An implementation could just allocate pointers from different bins for different sizes. Also there are many scenarios where it might require more than `2*sizeof(void*)`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, Yes, we're talking about the theoretical minimum here, not the practical scenarios.  At a minimum, the heap manager needs a  pointer to its arena, and the user gets a pointer to the space in that arena, both are overhead.  Of course this assumes that the heap manager can forgo overhead for tracking sub-blocks from multiple allocations right up to the point where it issues the second allocation.

Answer (score 2):

For allocated objects, no additional metadata is theoretically required.  A conforming implementation of `malloc` could round up all allocation requests to a fixed maximum object size, for example.  So for `malloc (25)`, you would actually receive a 256-byte buffer, and `malloc (257)` would fail and return a null pointer.

More realistically, some `malloc` implementations encode the allocation size in the pointer itself, either directly using bit patterns corresponding to specific fixed sized classes, or indirectly using a hash table or a multi-level trie.  If I recall correctly, the internal `malloc` for Address Sanitizer is of this type.  For such `malloc`s, at least part of the immediate allocation overhead does not come from the addition of metadata for heap management, but from rounding the allocation size up to a supported size class.

Other `malloc`s have a per-allocation header of a single word.  (`dlmalloc` and its derivative are popular examples).  The actual per-allocation overhead is usually slightly larger because due to the header word, you get weired supported allocation sizes (such as 24, 40, 56, … bytes with 16-byte alignment on a 64-bit system).

One thing to keep in mind is that many `malloc` implementations put a lot of data *deallocated* objects (which have not yet been returned to the operating system kernel), so that `malloc` (the function) can quickly find an unused memory region of the appropriate size.  Particularly for `dlmalloc`-style allocators, this also provides a constraint on minimum object size.  The use of deallocated objects for heap management contributes to `malloc` overhead, too, but its impact on individual allocations is difficult to quantify.

Comment: A conforming implementation must at least track which blocks are available for allocation and which are in use, or leave that overhead up to the OS.  In addition, I would contend that in the block oriented scheme, the unused bytes in each allocation are indeed overhead, perhaps higher overhead in many cases than if the implementation tracked blocks, block sizes and was able to combine/split blocks as needs arise.

Comment: It is possible to use deallocated objects only for the tracking. Allocated objects probably should not be tracked at all by a good implementation (for performance reasons, so that allocation performance is independent of working set size). The only challenge is how to recover the allocation size for `free`.

Comment: In any case, there's some bookkeeping overhead required.

Answer (score 1):

> Say, if I call malloc(sizeof(int)), requesting 4 bytes, how much extra will be added by system (or std library?) to support memory management infrastructure? I believe there should be some. Otherwise, how the system would know how many bytes to dispose of when I call free(ptr).

This is entirely library specific. The answer could be anything from zero to whatever. Your library could add data to the front of the block. Some add data to the front and back of the block to track overwrites. The amount of overhead added varies among libraries.

The length could be tracked within the library itself with a table. In that case, there may not be hidden field added to the allocated memory.

The library might only allocate blocks in fixed sizes. The amount you ask for gets rounded up to the next block size.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `malloc` rounds up to a minimum alignment boundary and often this is not special cased for small allocations as applications are expected to aggregate many of these into a single allocation. The minimum alignment is often based on the largest required alignment for a load instruction in the architecture the code is running on. So with 128-bit SIMD (e.g. SSE or NEON) the minimum is 16 bytes. In practice there is a header as well which causes the minimum cost in size to be doubled. As SIMD register widths have increased, `malloc` hasn't increased it's guaranteed alignment.

As was pointed out, the minimum possible overhead is 0. Though the pointer itself should probably be counted in any reasonable analysis. In a garbage collector design, at least one pointer to the data has to be present. In straight a non-GC design, one has to have a pointer to call `free`, but there's not an iron clad requirement it has to be called. One could theoretically compress a bunch of pointers together into less space as well, but now we're into an analysis of the entropy of the bits in the pointers. Point being you likely need to specify some more constraints to get a really solid answer.

By way of illustration, if one needs arbitrary allocation and deallocation of just `int` size, one can allocate a large block and create a linked list of indexes using each `int` to hold the index of the next. Allocation pulls an item off the list and deallocation adds one back. There is a constraint that each allocation is exactly an `int`. (And that the block is small enough that the maximum index fits in an `int`.) Multiple sizes can be handled by having different blocks and searching for which block the pointer is in when deallocation happens. Some `malloc` implementations do something like this for small fixed sizes such as 4, 8, and 16 bytes.

This approach doesn't hit zero overhead as one needs to maintain some data structure to keep track of the blocks. This is illustrated by considering the case of one-byte allocations. A block can at most hold 256 allocations as that is the maximum index that can fit in the block. If we want to allow more allocations than this, we will need at least one pointer per block, which is e.g. 4 or 8 bytes overhead per 256 bytes.

One can also use bitmaps, which amortize to one bit per some granularity plus the quantization of that granularity. Whether this is low overhead or not depends on the specifics. E.g. one bit per byte has no quantization but eats one eighth the allocation size in the free map. Generally this will all require storing the size of the allocation.

In practice allocator design is hard because the trade-off space between size overhead, runtime cost, and fragmentation overhead is complicated, often has large cost differences, and is allocation pattern dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer itself is essentially overhead and can be a dominant driver of memory use in some programs.

The theoretical minimum overhead, might be `sizeof(void*)` for some theoretical system and use, but that combination of CPU, Memory and usage pattern is so unlikely to exist as to be absolutely worthless for consideration. The standard requires that memory returned by malloc be suitably aligned for any data type, therefore there will always be some overhead; in the form of unused memory between the end of one allocated block, and the beginning of the next allocated block, except in the rare cases where all memory usage is sized to a multiple of the block size.

The minimum implementation of malloc/free/realloc, assumes the heap manager has one contiguous block of memory at it's disposal, located somewhere in system memory, the pointer that said heap manager uses to reference that original block, is overhead (again `sizeof(void*)`). One could imagine a highly contrived application that requested that entire block of memory, thus avoiding the need for additional tracking data. At this point we have `2 * sizeof(void*)` worth of overhead, one internal to the heap manager, plus the returned pointer to the one allocated block (the theoretical minimum). Such a conforming heap manager is unlikely to exist as it must also have some means of allocating more than one block from its pool and that implies at a minimum, tracking which blocks within its pool are in use.

One scheme to avoid overhead involves using pointer sizes that are larger than the physical or logical memory available to the application. One can store some information in those unused bits, but they would also count as overhead if their number exceeds a processor word size. Generally, only a hand full of bits are used and those identify which of the memory managers internal pools the memory comes from. The later, implies additonal overhead of pointers to pools.  This brings us to real world systems, where the heap manager implementation is tuned to the OS, hardware architecture and typical usage patterns.

Most hosted implementations (hosted == runs on OS) request one or more memory blocks from the operating system in the c-runtime initialization phase. OS memory management calls are expensive in time and space. The OS has it's own memory manager, with its own overhead set, driven by its own design criteria and usage patterns. So c-runtime heap managers attempt to limit the number of calls into the OS memory manager, in order to reduce the latency of the average call to `malloc()` and `free()`. Most request the first block from the OS when malloc is first called, but this usually happens at some point in the c-runtime initialization code. This first block is usually a low multiple of the system page size, which can be one or more orders of magnitude larger than the size requested in the initial `malloc()` call.

At this point it is obvious that heap manager overhead is extremely fluid and difficult to quantify. On a typical modern system, the heap manager must track multiple blocks of memory allocated from the OS, how many bytes are currently allocated to the application in each of those blocks and potentially, how much time has passed since a block went to zero.  Then there's the overhead of tracking allocations from within each of those blocks.